# Good way to create IDs for server-side storage?

Tags: java, json

I'm currently working on a project where we're being asked to store and receive recipes from a server. The recipes are stored in json format at the server ip + an id. I've been thinking about a good way to create an ID that is guaranteed not to be overlapping between two recipes that we're submitting. Is there a standard excepted way to create these IDs, or is it a better idea to just store an int keeping track of the biggest ID and pull that whenever someone wants to store a recipe server-side?

Thanks in advance,
Classy

```
public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe, String URL) throws IllegalStateException,     IOException{
    // TODO Implement the server-side ID tracking
    //int id = getID();
    //recipe.setId(id);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL+recipe.getId());
    StringEntity stringEntity = null;
    try {
        stringEntity = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(recipe));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept","application/json");

    httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    //      String status = response.getStatusLine().toString();
    //      System.out.println(status);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    try {
        // May need if statement, check isStreaming();
        entity.consumeContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //May possibly need to deallocate more resources here. No 4.0 implementation of releaseconnection();
}
```

Maybe this code will help? This is how I've been storing the recipes onto the server.

Comment: How is your data stored? An `autoincrement` column in a SQL db would solve this, e.g.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as the server-side is set up for us, we only need pull and search from it, but i believe it's elasticsearch? if that makes sense?

Comment: We need to see some code and a bit more context to be able to help you, I think.

Comment: If the server is setup for you, why are you concerned about ID generation? It's the server's job, so let it generate by the guys who setup the server.

Answer (score 0):

All database vendors support some sort of (surrogate) ID generation mechanisms.

If you store your object in a database you can use it.

If you store your objects in LDAP, you can use the node DN for this purpose.

Another alternative is to use some natural identifier, for example passport number, of social security (bad idea, but just to explain the nature), plate number for a car, or a combination of them that uniquely identifies your object.

You don't necessarily have to use some sort of surrogate (practically - numeric type) Id.

People often forget about natural primary keys, but they can be really helpful.

In your case it may be server ip + timestamp when the recipe was published.

But two servers can publish the same recipe.
How will you distinguish between them?

Will you treat them as equal or not?

You are the one who defines the identity for your objects.

It depends on your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind generating one using java, you can use [UUID](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) as follows:

```
UUID identifier = UUID.fromString(gson.toJson(recipe));
// use Strings as your id field
String uuidUniqueId = identifier.toString();
```

Nevertheless, I strongly recommend letting your database handle id generation. After all, the database knows better how to optimise storage for objects than we on StackOverflow (or the good people at Oracle) do.